# Kotlin JS: Is it possible to set up a Kotlin Web application with Spring Boot and Kotlin/JS(without front-end framework)?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-js

I've been reading books and trying examples for Kotlin full-stack development, but they all have one thing in common, that they are built for SPA apps and the logic is heavy on the client side. Instead, I want to build a web application in which the business logic is heavy on the server side, while the client side will be light and mostly for user interaction only. I'd like to build a traditional Spring Boot JVM application with server side rendering(the typical routing annotation GetMapping and PostMapping, with freemarker or thymeleaf templates), while the client side is light and mostly done with basic technology.

So my question is, is it possible to set up Kotlin JS so that I can write the client side logic in Kotlin instead of Javascript? I no need front end framework, maybe at most JQuery, and that is it. Basically, just a traditional server-side app, but with client side code written in Kotlin with Kotlin JS.

Is this doable for Kotlin multi-platform? And if so, can anyone show me how to set up such a project in IntelliJ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. Keep in mind that Kotlin Multiplatform is the platform to share code between your targets. For example you could store some DTO models in a common project and share it between your Kotlin JVM backend and the Kotlin JS front end.
You asked for Kotlin JS, which can be used without a multiplatform setup. So if you don't need shared common code, you could simply add separate koltin-js module which generates a javasctipt file n build. This could be served by spring and included in a template generated html file:

#### index.html

```html
<html>
  <body>
  <!-- Link to the compiled js files-->
  <script src="kotlin.js"></script>
  <!-- Link to the compiled js files-->
  <script src="output.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### build.gradle.kts

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("kotlin2js") version "1.5.0"
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-js"))
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

tasks {
    compileKotlin2Js {
        kotlinOptions {
            outputFile = "${sourceSets.main.get().output.resourcesDir}/output.js"
            sourceMap = true
        }
    }
}
```

You can find a simple Kotlin-JS project which doesn't use any frameworks here:
https://github.com/TobseF/KotlinJsGameWishlist

Kotlin multiplatform in addition is even more powerful because of the common code module. So it should be also possible there.

Comment: I see, thanks your answer. Yeah I just want to build a traditional Multi-page app with server side rendering, the client side will be mostly thin.